# Por que una llamada a un servicio SOAP desde un WebAPi arroja un error?

Tags: c#, soap, asp.net-web-api

Estoy intentando hacer una llamada a un servicio web SOAP desde un metodo en un WebAPI. Esto me arroja este error:

> ```
> An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still
> pending
> ```

Pero no estoy llamando al servicio SOAP con metodos async

¿Qué puede estar causando este error?

Codigo de llamada

```
     using IS3 = Siscore3.WebAPI.identificativosServicio3;

     public class PersonaRepository : IDisposable
    {
     public SPersona ConsultarIdentificativos(int idUsuario, string numeroCliente)
    {           
        try
        {
            IS3.ServiceSoapClient consulta = new IS3.ServiceSoapClient();
            IS3.Cliente[] clientes = consulta.ConsultaClientexId(numeroCliente);

           //Aqui hay mas codigo....

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
              //Codigo de control de errores....
            }

    }
}
```

Metodo del WebApi:

```
    private PersonaRepository personaContexto = new PersonaRepository();

    [Route("api/Cliente/Buscar/{numeroCliente}")]
    [HttpPost]
    public SPersona ConsultarIdentificativos(string numeroCliente)
    {
        SPersona persona = personaContexto.ConsultarIdentificativos(1,  numeroCliente);
        return persona;
    }
```

Desmarqué el checkbox para crear operaciones asincronas:

[image: Desmarque el checkbox para crear operaciones asincronas]

Comment: Deberías mostrar algo de codigo, en concreto donde realizas la llamada

Comment: Listo @Pikoh , gracias por la sugerencia

Comment: Es posible que el cliente SOAP esté invocando un método asíncrono. Puedes comprobar que `consulta.ConsultaClientexId` no invoca por detrás un método asíncrono?

Comment: @frikinside como puedo comprobar eso? te comento que desmarque el checkbox para crear operaciones asincronas cuando agregue la referencia web: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hij6s.png

Comment: Ese asistente en principio te crea una clase (en este caso `Siscore3.WebAPI.identificativosServicio3.ServiceSoapClient`) puede ir a esa clase y revisar si alguno de los métodos que hay ahí implementados se encuentra definido para ser ejecutado de forma asíncrona. Que parecería que no, por que así se lo indicaste tu en el tutorial, pero por revisarlo por si acaso.